# Sub menu won't display

Tags: html, css, submenu

I have a hover drop down menu on my website. It displays ok until you hover over. The submenu appears but before you can click on a link, the sub menu vanishes.

Here is the HTML -

```
<div id="top-nav"><div id="nav">

<nav>
<ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none;">

    <li id="sub"><a href="#">Artists</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Banks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lil Silva</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Frances and the Lights</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jim-E Stack</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Night</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS -

```
#nav {
text-align:center;
list-style: none;

}
ul#menu {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
width: 300px;

}
ul#menu:after {
content: "";
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
margin-top: 20px;

}
ul#menu li {
float: left;
}
ul#menu li a {
color: #666666;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 35px;
text-decoration: none;

}
ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #ccc;
}
a.selected-page, ul#menu a.selected-page:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
li#sub ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 22222;
margin-top: 4px;
overflow: hidden;
}
li#sub ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
border-top-style: none;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;

}
ul#menu li#sub:hover ul {
display: block;
}
ul#menu li#sub ul li:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like dalucks said, remove the top margin from your CSS:

```
li#sub ul {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Also, reduce the left margin/paddings from the submenu UL and/or LI children. With the original large values (35px) the menu could be hovered over a lot of invisible space.

```
ul#menu li ul li a {
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LXwTr/

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the following line of your CSS code:

```
li#sub ul {
    ...
    margin-top: 4px;
    ...
}
```

Just remove this margin-top and your drop down menu will work properly.

In your example there is a 4px margin space between the "Artists"-link and the drop down menu below. And if your cursors leaves the link and enters this "margin area", the browser interprets it as un-hovering the link - and hides the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Add Padding: 0 to this

```
li#sub ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tdQmE/